# Docker container exits without any message

Tags: docker, coreos, xinetd

I'm trying to run xinetd in a Docker container.

My Docker file is very basic:

```
# voip-monitor
#
# VERSION               0.0.1
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y xinetd python 

EXPOSE 9090 
CMD ["/usr/sbin/xinetd", "-d -dontfork"]
```

When I start my container with:

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --name voip-monitor voip-monitor
```

It starts but exists after 2 seconds.

When I start my container with:

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --name voip-monitor voip-monitor /usr/sbin/xinetd -d -dontfork
```

It works as expected. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the "-d" parameter?

I tried to launch a container based on your image and here's what I got:

```
root@r2d2:/tmp/tmp# docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --name voip-monitor voip-monitor
e482c8d486134749c6f2747c252eed96f628924c4158c05ca09ac487ff87db24
root@r2d2:/tmp/tmp# docker logs voip-monitor 
xinetd: msg_init failed: can't open log file
```

Checking the source code I think this [line](https://github.com/xinetd-org/xinetd/blob/7cd40659b61ffa0bab27e1acc5d5463223b9389d/xinetd/msg.c#L54) could be the problem, probably related to /dev/tty access.

Removing the "-d" parameter solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the `-d` and `-dontfork` options are put into the same array element/string in the `Dockerfile` above:

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/xinetd", "-d -dontfork"]
```

Correcting the `CMD` instruction to

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/xinetd", "-d", "-dontfork"]
```

should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While, the `-d` is possibly not needed, many of us love the verbose option. To emulate a tty and make xinetd happy, try using the script command.

```
script -c "xinetd -d -dontfork"
```

Which becomes

```
CMD ["script", "-c", "xinetd -d -dontfork"]
or
CMD script -c "xinet -d -dontfork"
```

Works with the debian:8 image using docker 1.13.0